# Disable command bar completion list

Tags: neovim, wildmenu

when I use  to autocomplete in neovim, I get two completion lists. The following screenshot was taken with an empty .nvimrc.
[image: Neovim with two completion lists]

To reproduce: Open `nvim`, enter `:e`, tab `<Tab>` to get the (in this case) blue completion list, then tab `<Tab>` again to get the second interactive list.

I would like to disable the blue completion list, is that possible?
I also noticed that `vim` does indeed only shows me the second list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The yellow "interactive" list is called the "wildmenu". You can enable & disable
this with the `'wildmenu'` setting.

The `'wildmode'` setting controls when to show this menu. If this contains the
`list` keyword, it will list all possible completions.

You probably want to use `set wildmode=full`, but see `:help wildmode` for more
options.

The defaults are:

`wildmenu`:

- Vim: Off
- NeoVim: On

`wildmode`:

- Vim: `full`
- NeoVim: `list:longest,full`